# Does libhdfs c/c++ api support read/write compressed file

Tags: api, hadoop, hdfs

I have found somebody talks libhdfs does not support read/write gzip file at about 2010.

I download the newest hadoop-2.0.4 and read hdfs.h. There is also no compressing arguments.

Now I am wondering if it supports reading compressed file now?

If it not, how can I make a patch for the libhdfs and make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards
Haiti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have known, **libhdfs** only uses **JNI** to access the HDFS. If you are familiar with HDFS Java API, **libhdfs** is just a wrapper of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream`. So it can not read compressed files directly now.

I guess that you want to access the file in the HDFS by C/C++. If so, you can use **libhdfs** to read the raw file, and use the zip/unzip C/C++ library to decompress the content. The compressed file format is the same. For example, if the files are compressed by lzo, then you can use [lzo](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/) library to decompress them.

But if the file is a sequence file, then you may need to use the JNI to access them as they are Hadoop special file. I have seen [Impala](https://github.com/cloudera/impala) does the similar work before. But it's not out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. Use libhdfs to read raw file, then use zlib to inflate the content. This can work. The file used gzip. I used the codes like these.

```
z_stream gzip_stream;

gzip_stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)0;
gzip_stream.zfree = (free_func)0;
gzip_stream.opaque = (voidpf)0;

gzip_stream.next_in  = buf;
gzip_stream.avail_in = readlen;
gzip_stream.next_out = buf1;
gzip_stream.avail_out = 4096 * 4096;

ret = inflateInit2(&gzip_stream, 16 + MAX_WBITS);
if (ret != Z_OK) {
    printf("deflate init error\n");
}   
ret = inflate(&gzip_stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
ret = inflateEnd(&gzip_stream);
printf("the buf \n%s\n", buf1);

return buf;
```